# Is Earning Money From Youtube Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, work, internet

If i share Islamic Content on YouTube and if i block abusive advertisement will the earning will be halal for me ?

Comment: What makes you think its Haram?

Comment: Actually Some People Say But They Can't Explain Properly.That's Why I Asked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major rule in Islam : every thing is originally Halal till we prove otherwise. So , a proof is needed from those claim that YouTube work is Haram.

My answer is : since you broadcast useful content and block   abusive ads as much as you can, then it is Halal inshaallah .